# How to use join() on an object that looks like an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains key pair values of objects that are in array form:

```
let obj = {};
let joinedData;

obj["key1"] = ["val1", "val2"];
obj["key2"] = ["val3", "val4"];
```

I want to join all the values together as a string:

```
for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    joinedData = `${values.join(",")}`;
}
```

The expected result is `"val1,val2,val3,val4"`

But `joinedData` is empty.

I suspect that it's because the `values` are objects and not array (when I use `typeof`).

How to get the expected result in this case?

Comment: `values` is an array (`typeof` doesn't make any difference between arrays and objects). A simple one would be: No loop, just `joinedData = Object.values(obj).join(',');`.

Comment: For the shown code `joinedData` is `val3,val4` and not empty?

Comment: You replace the value assigned to `joinedData` in each iteration instead of updating it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` and `flat`:

```js
let obj = { key1: ["val1", "val2"], key2: ["val3", "val4"] };
let joinedData = Object.values(obj).flat().join();

console.log(joinedData);
```

If you have some arrays that contain empty strings, then you may want to filter those out, with `filter(Boolean)`:

```js
let obj = { key1: ["val1", "val2"], key2: ["val3", "val4"], key3: [""], key4: [""] };
let joinedData = Object.values(obj).flat().filter(Boolean).join();

console.log(joinedData);
```

Comment: Thank you. The only issue is that if the arrays are empty (it's dynamic), then it adds commas at the end. In my case I actually have 4 arrays then the result is `val1,val2,val3,val4,,`. Any way to remove those trailing commas when the number of the arrays inside this object is unknown?

Comment: That means you have some arrays that are not empty but have empty strings as *elements*. If you want to avoid any empty strings, then do `Object.values(obj).flat().filter(Boolean).join()`. See addition to answer.

Comment: Awesome. In fact I was wrong in the first place, I accidentally ran it twice and not because I had empty strings as elements. But I learned the filter part as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use this - `joinedData = Object.values(obj).flat().join(',')`

Answer (score 1):

get all values from obj using `let objValues = Object.values(obj);`

now you can a for loop over obj values and append both elms like `for(const v of objValues) { joinedData.push(v[0]); joinedData.push(v[1]); }` or nested for loop works too

```js
let obj = {};
let joinedData = [];

obj["key1"] = ["val1", "val2"];
obj["key2"] = ["val3", "val4"];

let objValues = Object.values(obj); //List of tuples ?

for (const v of objValues) {
  joinedData += v[0] + ',';
  joinedData += v[1] + ' ';
}

console.log(joinedData)
```

Answer (score 1):

First join the both list in any single list like

```
var newlist = obj["key1"].join(obj["key2"]);
```

After join the values by comma seprated

```
joinedData = newlist.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you were to write out your object literally, you would have:

```
 obj = {key1 : ["val1", "val2"], key2 : ["val3", "val4"]}
```

`Array.join()` concatenates array elements into a string.  Array elements that are arrays themselves cannot be directly concatenated into a string.  Try:

```
let str = '';
for(let i of Object.values(obj)) {  // retrieve each value (which is an array)
    str += i.join(', ') + ', ';    //  join elements of each array & concatenate
}                                  //   extra comma between each joined array
console.log(str)
```

You still need to strip the extra comma off the end

Comment: This solution adds a trailing `, ` at the end of the list, further more if at least one of the arrays is empty, you would get `, , `.